# viewWillTransitionToSize returns wrong size for iPhone 12 pro max

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Today, I found a bug.

***viewWillTransitionToSize*** method in ViewController returns wrong size for iPhone 12 pro max device. But for simulator, the size is correct. How to I fix it? Any idea?

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
 
    NSLog(@"ww hh %f %f", size.width, size.height);
    
}
```

Result for iphone 12 pro max device:  ww hh 812.000000 375.000000 <- **not correct**

result for iphone 12 pro max simulator: ww hh 926.000000 428.000000 <- correct

iphone 12 max pro screen size in pixels is 2778 x 1284
divide it to 3 we have = 926 x 428 points

xCode 12.5, iOS 14.5

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the matter.
If in the phone settings there is an enlarged view on the screen (settings - display - displays zoom - zoomed) then the screen resolution changes in dots.

crime solved! ))